# dplyr: Group_by() and run a regression

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to run a regression (extract the betas) from a number of models.

Here I have 3 firms (BABA, GOOG, AMZN) and 1 benchmark (SPY). I am trying to `group_by(symbol)` and run a regression for each of the firms on the benchmark.

So BABA will be run on the SPY

GOOG will be the second one run on the SPY

and finally AMZN will be the third run on the SPY

So each firm run on a fixed SPY

I have be trying the following without luck;

```
df %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  do(mod = lm(SPY ~ ., data = .))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(symbol = c("BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", 
"BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", 
"BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", 
"BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", 
"BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "BABA", "GOOG", 
"GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
"GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
"GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
"GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
"GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", 
"AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", 
"AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", 
"AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", 
"AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "AMZN", "SPY", 
"SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", 
"SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", 
"SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", 
"SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY", "SPY"), date = structure(c(16708, 
16738, 16769, 16800, 16829, 16860, 16891, 16920, 16952, 16982, 
17011, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17165, 17197, 17225, 17256, 
17284, 17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17438, 17470, 17500, 17529, 
17562, 17590, 17619, 17651, 17682, 17711, 17743, 17774, 16708, 
16738, 16769, 16800, 16829, 16860, 16891, 16920, 16952, 16982, 
17011, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17165, 17197, 17225, 17256, 
17284, 17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17438, 17470, 17500, 17529, 
17562, 17590, 17619, 17651, 17682, 17711, 17743, 17774, 16708, 
16738, 16769, 16800, 16829, 16860, 16891, 16920, 16952, 16982, 
17011, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17165, 17197, 17225, 17256, 
17284, 17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17438, 17470, 17500, 17529, 
17562, 17590, 17619, 17651, 17682, 17711, 17743, 17774, 16708, 
16738, 16769, 16800, 16829, 16860, 16891, 16920, 16952, 16982, 
17011, 17044, 17074, 17105, 17135, 17165, 17197, 17225, 17256, 
17284, 17317, 17347, 17378, 17409, 17438, 17470, 17500, 17529, 
17562, 17590, 17619, 17651, 17682, 17711, 17743, 17774), class = "Date"), 
    close = c(58.970001, 83.830002, 84.080002, 81.269997, 67.029999, 
    68.809998, 79.029999, 76.940002, 82, 79.529999, 82.480003, 
    97.190002, 105.790001, 101.690002, 94.019997, 87.809998, 
    101.309998, 102.900002, 107.830002, 115.5, 122.459999, 140.899994, 
    154.949997, 171.740005, 172.710007, 184.889999, 177.080002, 
    172.429993, 204.289993, 186.139999, 183.539993, 178.539993, 
    198.009995, 185.529999, 187.229996, 175.009995, 608.419983, 
    710.809998, 742.599976, 758.880005, 742.950012, 697.77002, 
    744.950012, 693.01001, 735.719971, 692.099976, 768.789978, 
    767.049988, 777.289978, 784.539978, 758.039978, 771.820007, 
    796.789978, 823.210022, 829.559998, 905.960022, 964.859985, 
    908.72998, 930.5, 939.330017, 959.109985, 1016.640015, 1021.409973, 
    1046.400024, 1169.939941, 1104.72998, 1031.790039, 1017.330017, 
    1084.98999, 1115.650024, 1217.26001, 1218.189941, 511.890015, 
    625.900024, 664.799988, 675.890015, 587, 552.52002, 593.640015, 
    659.590027, 722.789978, 715.619995, 758.809998, 769.159973, 
    837.309998, 789.820007, 750.570007, 749.869995, 823.47998, 
    845.039978, 886.539978, 924.98999, 994.619995, 968, 987.780029, 
    980.599976, 961.349976, 1105.280029, 1176.75, 1169.469971, 
    1450.890015, 1512.449951, 1447.339966, 1566.130005, 1629.619995, 
    1699.800049, 1777.439941, 2012.709961, 191.589996, 207.929993, 
    208.690002, 203.869995, 193.720001, 193.559998, 205.520004, 
    206.330002, 209.839996, 209.479996, 217.119995, 217.380005, 
    216.300003, 212.550003, 220.380005, 223.529999, 227.529999, 
    236.470001, 235.740005, 238.080002, 241.440002, 241.800003, 
    246.770004, 247.490005, 251.229996, 257.149994, 265.01001, 
    266.859985, 281.899994, 271.649994, 263.149994, 264.51001, 
    270.940002, 271.279999, 281.329987, 290.309998), returns = c(NA, 
    0.421570299786836, 0.00298222586228736, -0.0334206105275782, 
    -0.17521838963523, 0.0265552592354952, 0.14852494255268, 
    -0.0264456159236444, 0.0657655038792433, -0.0301219634146341, 
    0.0370929716722364, 0.178346247150355, 0.0884864576913991, 
    -0.0387560162703845, -0.0754253599090302, -0.0660497681147555, 
    0.153741035274821, 0.015694443109159, 0.047910591877345, 
    0.0711304633009282, 0.0602597316017315, 0.150579741552995, 
    0.0997161362547681, 0.108357588416087, 0.00564808414906004, 
    0.0705227925791236, -0.0422413166869019, -0.0262593683503574, 
    0.184770639061616, -0.0888442636541674, -0.0139680133983453, 
    -0.0272420191276787, 0.109051208487501, -0.0630271012329453, 
    0.00916292248780737, -0.0652673250070464, NA, 0.168288382796263, 
    0.0447235943352615, 0.0219230130974311, -0.020991451738144, 
    -0.0608116175654627, 0.0676153899532685, -0.0697228017495488, 
    0.06162964514755, -0.0592888554332855, 0.110807693482712, 
    -0.00226328392641983, 0.0133498339876124, 0.00932727837126435, 
    -0.0337777560648413, 0.0181784990237019, 0.0323520649549578, 
    0.0331581027993302, 0.00771367674141366, 0.0920970444382494, 
    0.0650138654793755, -0.0581742489818355, 0.0239565332707523, 
    0.00948954003224078, 0.0210575278571132, 0.0599827245047395, 
    0.00469188496382378, 0.0244662296830735, 0.118061844578092, 
    -0.0557378705647592, -0.0660251304124109, -0.0140145004830774, 
    0.0665073986507567, 0.0282583565586627, 0.0910769361485713, 
    0.000763954284508372, NA, 0.222723643085712, 0.0621504433749629, 
    0.0166817496994298, -0.131515502562943, -0.0587393185689948, 
    0.0744226335907248, 0.111094283292207, 0.0958170202897868, 
    -0.00991987052703713, 0.0603532647239684, 0.0136397451631891, 
    0.0886031871031852, -0.0567173342172369, -0.0496948667444936, 
    -0.000932640517835148, 0.0981636623558995, 0.0261815691014129, 
    0.0491101025755256, 0.0433708721029611, 0.0752764956948344, 
    -0.0267639853751381, 0.0204339142561984, -0.00726887848428048, 
    -0.0196308387427495, 0.149716603311175, 0.0646623200680305, 
    -0.00618655534310597, 0.240638965495934, 0.0424290851570854, 
    -0.0430493484805567, 0.0820747314318273, 0.0405394123076008, 
    0.043065287745196, 0.0456758970242859, 0.13236453990543, 
    NA, 0.0852862745505771, 0.00365511963442433, -0.0230964921836553, 
    -0.0497866005245156, -0.000825949820225325, 0.0617896575923709, 
    0.00394121245735279, 0.0170115541413121, -0.00171559286533729, 
    0.0364712580956894, 0.00119754055816013, -0.0049682674356365, 
    -0.0173370316596806, 0.0368383998564328, 0.0142934655074538, 
    0.0178946898308714, 0.0392915309598361, -0.00308705542738164, 
    0.00992617693377928, 0.0141129031072504, 0.00149105780739678, 
    0.0205541808864245, 0.00291770064565866, 0.0151116850153201, 
    0.0235640572155245, 0.0305658805498554, 0.00698077404698783, 
    0.0563591765172287, -0.0363604122673377, -0.0312902638974474, 
    0.00516821596431427, 0.0243090686813703, 0.00125487929980883, 
    0.037046549826919, 0.0319198500513918)), .Names = c("symbol", 
"date", "close", "returns"), row.names = c(NA, -144L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "symbol", indices = list(
    72:107, 0:35, 36:71, 108:143), group_sizes = c(36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L), biggest_group_size = 36L, labels = structure(list(
    symbol = c("AMZN", "BABA", "GOOG", "SPY")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame", vars = "symbol", .Names = "symbol"))
```

EDIT:

I am getting different results:

Here is the basic model:

```
symbols <- c("GOOG")

start_date_beta = "2015-09-01"
end_date_beta = "2018-09-01"

library(tidyquant)
stock_returns <- symbols %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from =  start_date_beta,
         to =  end_date_beta) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = open:volume,
               mutate_fun = to.period,
               period = "months") %>%
  select(date, close)


bench <- "SPY"
bench_returns <- bench %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from =  start_date_beta,
         to =  end_date_beta) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = open:volume,
               mutate_fun = to.period,
               period = "months") %>%
  select(date, close)

returns <- full_join(stock_returns, bench_returns, by = "date")
colnames(returns) <- c("date", "GOOG", "SPY")


returns$GOOGret <- Delt(returns$GOOG)
returns$SPYret <- Delt(returns$SPY)

lm(returns$GOOGret ~ returns$SPYret)$coeff[[2]]

> lm(returns$GOOGret ~ returns$SPYret)$coeff[[2]]
[1] 1.412548
```

Here is the more advanced model

```
symbols_beta <- c("BABA", "GOOG", "AMZN")
start_date_beta = "2015-09-01"
end_date_beta = "2018-09-01"

library(tidyquant)
stock_prices <- symbols_beta %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from =  start_date_beta,
         to =  end_date_beta)

stock_periods <- stock_prices %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = open:volume,
               mutate_fun = to.period,
               period = "months") %>%
  select(symbol, date, close)


bench <- "SPY"
bench_prices <- bench %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices",
         from =  start_date_beta,
         to =  end_date_beta)

bench_prices$symbol <- "SPY"


bench_periods <- bench_prices %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = open:volume,
               mutate_fun = to.period,
               period = "months") %>%
  select(symbol, date, close)

returns <- rbind(stock_periods, bench_periods)

returns <- returns %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  mutate(returns = Delt(close))


library(tidyverse)

returns = ungroup(returns)

imap_dbl(unique(returns$symbol)[unique(returns$symbol) != "SPY"] %>% set_names(),

         ~ left_join(returns %>% filter(symbol=="SPY") %>% 
                       select(date, spy_returns=returns),
                     returns %>% filter(symbol==.x) %>% 
                       select(date, !!.y:=returns),
                     by="date") %>% 
           lm(paste("spy_returns ~ ", .y), data=.) %>% 
           coef() %>% .[2]
)

     BABA      GOOG      AMZN 
0.1533903 0.3290332 0.2306936
```

Comment: There is no `SPY` column

Comment: SPY is at the very end of the `symbol` column

Comment: What akrun is saying is that when you tell R to fit a model with `SPY ~ .` what that means is you're telling it that there is a column called `SPY` in your data frame.

Comment: ah right, I see. Should I perhaps just "repeat" the SPY data 3 times (for each firm) into a separate column?

Comment: What do you want to find out about your data? I think it would help to know which questions you are looking to answer.

Comment: So, I am trying to find the beta values for each firm using the SPY as the benchmark. This comes from the period returns. If I had just BABA and the SPY then I would get what I am after using.  `lm(df$BABAreturns ~ df$SPYreturns)$coeff[[2]]` where BABA and SPY returns are in two separate columns.

Comment: You should be able to archiev this by: dfspy = filter(df, symbol == "SPY"); df_others = filter(df, symbol != "SPY"); models = df_others %>% group_by(symbol) %>% do(mod = lm(.$returns ~ dfspy$returns, data = .)); models$mod but be sure, that the data is in the correct order! This is a quite dangerous approach and i think, to make sure that ordering is ok, you should merge your non_spy  and spy cases by some id

Answer (score 0):

You need the returns for SPY and the second symbol to be in separate columns. You could use `imap` from the `purrr` package to iterate over the non-SPY stock symbols. For example, in the code below, iterating over each non-SPY symbol, we use `left_join` (joining on `date`) to create a data frame of SPY returns and the returns of the other stock. Then we run a regression and return the second coefficient of each regression as a named vector:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = ungroup(df)

imap_dbl(unique(df$symbol)[unique(df$symbol) != "SPY"] %>% set_names(),

         ~ left_join(df %>% filter(symbol=="SPY") %>% 
                       select(date, spy_returns=returns),
                     df %>% filter(symbol==.x) %>% 
                       select(date, !!.y:=returns),
                     by="date") %>% 
           lm(paste("spy_returns ~ ", .y), data=.) %>% 
           coef() %>% .[2]
)
```

> ```
>      BABA      GOOG      AMZN 
> 0.1533903 0.3290332 0.2306936
> ```

Comment: I have tried to incorporate this into the model (I have not added code to replicate). I am obtaining different values. The value I should obtain for `GOOG` is 1.4125

Comment: I've only regressed returns of SPY vs. returns of the other stock. It looks like you're incorporating more variables in your model.